# Emacs から OS にキーを送る

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, cygwin

Cygwin 版の Emacs24.4 を使用しています。

Winのパッチが当たっていないので、Windows の IME を操作する関数が有りません。
私のマシンは 32bit の為、64bit のパッチがあたったバイナリが無いためです。
（自分でビルドすれば良いのですが、そこまでは頑張れません。ごめんなさい！）

しかし例えば VBScript の sendkeys のようにOSにキーを送る Emacs Lisp の関数は有るでしょうか？
そうすれば、好きなタイミングで無変換キーなどを呼び出すことで、IMEの操作が実質的に出来そうです。

もしもご存知の方がいましたら教えて下さい。